# R: Calculate linear regression and get slope for "a subset of data"

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My goal is to find out half life (from terminal phase if anyone is familiar with Pharmacokinetics)

I have some data containing the following;

1500 rows, with `ID` being main "key". There is 15 rows per `ID`. Then I have other columns `TIME` and `CONCENTRATION`. Now What I want to do is, for each `ID`, remove the first `TIME` (which equals "000" (numeric)), then run `lm()` function on the remaining 14 rows per `ID`, and then use abs() to extract the absolute value of the slope, then then save this to a new column named `THALF`. (If anyone is familiar with Pharmacokinetics maybe there is better way to do this?)

But I have not be able to do this using my limited knowledge of R.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
data_new <- data %>% dplyr::group_by(data $ID) %>% dplyr::filter(data $TIME != 10) %>% dplyr::mutate(THAFL = abs(lm$coefficients[2](data $CONC ~ data $TIME)))
```

From what I've understood from other Stackoverflow answers, lm$coefficients[2] will extract the slope.

But however, I have not been able to make this work. I get this error from trying to run the code:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 15.
i Input `..1` is `data$ID`.
i Input `..1` must be size 15 or 1, not 1500.
i The error occurred in group 1: data$ID = "pat1".
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this? IF you need more info, let me know please.

(Also, if anyone is familiar with Pharmacokinetics, when they ask for half life from terminal phase, do I  do lm() from the concentration max ? I Have a column with value for the highest observed concentration at what time. )

Comment: Hi Carlton, is possible to share a sample of data maybe using `dput(head(yourdata,100))`?

Comment: Also, don't specify `data$` inside dplyr statements, there's no need for it

Comment: @Duck Okay, I did that. Under edit.

Comment: I don't think there is enough data in there for you to try something. Do you want all the data? @Duck

Comment: In your sample data `TIME` is always 10, which means every row gets excluded. Maybe you can share all the rows for a few distinct `ID`s, say three or four

Comment: @RicS How can I output that? Just for 1 distinct ID is enough I would think.

Comment: You can use `data %>% filter(ID %in% c("pat1", "pat2", "pat3"))`

Comment: @RicS Its done now, check under edit please

Comment: I checked your data, but all `TIME` are 10, maybe can you upload your full data on github and add the link to download!

Comment: @Duck can you check under edit ,the new subdata?  its all the data for 2 ID values, i think it is enough? If not, I will put on github

Comment: Try this: `library(dplyr); data %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(TIME != 10) %>% summarize(THAFL = abs(lm(CONC ~ TIME)$coefficients[2]))`

Comment: @Dave2e Thanks for your input, I tried this. I still get the size error as above in the post. No idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If after the model fitting you still need the observations with `TIME == 10`, you can try summarising after you group by `ID` and then using a right join

```
data %>% 
  filter(TIME != 10) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(THAFL = abs(lm(CONC ~ TIME)$coefficients[2])) %>% 
  right_join(data, by = "ID")


# A tibble: 30 x 16
   ID      THAFL Sex   Weight..kg. Height..cm. Age..yrs. T134A A443G G769C G955C A990C  TIME  CONC LBM   `data_combine$ID`  CMAX
   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>       <int>       <int>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>             <dbl>
 1 pat1  0.00975 F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0    10  0    Under pat1                 60
 2 pat1  0.00975 F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0    20  6.93 Under pat1                 60
 3 pat1  0.00975 F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0    30 12.2  Under pat1                 60
 4 pat1  0.00975 F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0    45 14.8  Under pat1                 60
 5 pat1  0.00975 F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0    60 15.0  Under pat1                 60
 6 pat1  0.00975 F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0    90 12.4  Under pat1                 60
 7 pat1  0.00975 F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0   120  9.00 Under pat1                 60
 8 pat1  0.00975 F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0   150  6.22 Under pat1                 60
 9 pat1  0.00975 F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0   180  4.18 Under pat1                 60
10 pat1  0.00975 F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0   240  1.82 Under pat1                 60
# ... with 20 more rows
```

---

If after the model fitting you don't want the rows with `TIME == 10` to appear on your dataset, you can use `mutate`

```
data %>% 
  filter(TIME != 10) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(THAFL = abs(lm(CONC ~ TIME)$coefficients[2]))

# A tibble: 28 x 16
# Groups:   ID [2]
   ID    Sex   Weight..kg. Height..cm. Age..yrs. T134A A443G G769C G955C A990C  TIME  CONC LBM   `data_combine$ID`  CMAX   THAFL
   <chr> <chr>       <int>       <int>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>             <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 pat1  F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0    20  6.93 Under pat1                 60 0.00975
 2 pat2  M              75         175        29     0     2     0     0     0    20  6.78 Under pat2                 60 0.00835
 3 pat1  F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0    30 12.2  Under pat1                 60 0.00975
 4 pat2  M              75         175        29     0     2     0     0     0    30 11.6  Above pat2                 60 0.00835
 5 pat1  F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0    45 14.8  Under pat1                 60 0.00975
 6 pat2  M              75         175        29     0     2     0     0     0    45 13.5  Under pat2                 60 0.00835
 7 pat1  F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0    60 15.0  Under pat1                 60 0.00975
 8 pat2  M              75         175        29     0     2     0     0     0    60 13.1  Above pat2                 60 0.00835
 9 pat1  F              50         135        47     0     2     1     2     0    90 12.4  Under pat1                 60 0.00975
10 pat2  M              75         175        29     0     2     0     0     0    90  9.77 Under pat2                 60 0.00835
# ... with 18 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I need to filter additionally so that only rows where TIME >= CMAX, do i add an additional  filter() function, or do it in the same filter() i already have?

Comment: You can do it in the same `filter`statement: `filter(TIME != 10 & TIME >= CMAX)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `broom`:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
#Code
data %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(TIME!=10) %>%
  do(fit = tidy(lm(CONC ~ TIME, data = .))) %>% 
  unnest(fit) %>%
  filter(term=='TIME') %>%
  mutate(estimate=abs(estimate))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  ID    term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 pat1  TIME   0.00975   0.00334     -2.92  0.0128
2 pat2  TIME   0.00835   0.00313     -2.67  0.0204
```

If joining with original data is needed, try:

```
#Code 2
data <- data %>% left_join(data %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(TIME!=10) %>%
  do(fit = tidy(lm(CONC ~ TIME, data = .))) %>% 
  unnest(fit) %>%
  filter(term=='TIME') %>%
  mutate(estimate=abs(estimate)) %>%
  select(c(ID,estimate)))
```

Similar to **@RicS**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I need to filter additionally so that only rows where TIME >= CMAX, do i add an additional  filter() function, or do it in the same filter() i already have?

Comment: @Carlton You can add another filter() because if you add in the the first both conditions will be evaluated jointly. You could do `filter(TIME!=10|TIME >= CMAX)` in only one line!

Comment: @Carlton Also, `filter(TIME!=10,TIME >= CMAX)` will evaluate both conditions jointly!

Comment: Thank you for the help once again! Very helpful! I upvoted, but I have to accept the other answer sorry, he replied first. Apologies for that and thank you for the help!